# Django Admin set extra to 0 when editing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Setting `extra = 1`  in my model always shows a 1 empty field. It is OK while inserting a new item but I don't want to show an additional empty field while editing. How can I do this?

**models.py**:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, models.CASCADE, related_name='bars')
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(_('Body'))
    __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

**admin.py**:

```
class FooInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Foo
    extra = 1 #Also shows 1 extra empty field while editing.
              #I don't want to show if there is already a non-empty field

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    inlines = [FooInline]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override the [get_extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_extra) method instead of setting a value for extra class member.

> Returns the number of extra inline forms to use. By default, returns
>   the InlineModelAdmin.extra attribute.
>
> Override this method to programmatically determine the number of extra
>   inline forms. For example, this may be based on the model instance
>   (passed as the keyword argument obj):

Something like:

```
def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj.bar_set.count() :
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1
```

Comment: A further question, if I have multiple models let's say they are on same admin page, is there any way to inherit or should I hardcode this to every Inline model? (Sorry if I misused some terms)

Comment: yes, you can create your own base admin and extend that

Answer (score 1):

Use **"get_extra()"** to control **the number of extra empty fields** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class FooInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Foo
    # extra = 1

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            return 0 # For changing an item
        else: 
            return 1 # For adding a new item

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    inlines = [FooInline]
```